# How to Improve Visibility of Photos for an Article

Tags: photo-editing

I have written up a science experiment for high school students where I take some photos of a swinging pendulum but it has been pointed out the photos of the pendulum are hard to see and that the images should be improved with a better background or colour.

Unfortunately, it is going to be a bit difficult for me to re-do these images.  I was wondering what kind of tricks or software can be used on the photos to improve them (change the background so that the things in the background are not so visible, colour, more contrast and so on).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94857/how-to-capture-a-swinging-pendulum/94916#94916 I will review my answer there later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I honestly doubt there's much you can do at all in post - because your string is basically the same colour as the wall. Black curtain behind, or maybe black string, would have worked wonders - as would a higher ISO and faster shutter speed.
Example of overkill rescue attempt… gains nothing -

[image]

Comment: Hi Tesujin, I abandoned these photos and did some new ones which worked out well, thanks for the advice.